# Getting Errors for Circular Dependencies and on Forward Declarations

Tags: c++, header-files

I have 2 C++ classes that need to be able to access each other's resources in a sort of parent-child relationship. I originally had the following-ish code:

A.h:

```c++
#include "B.h"

class A {
    B *pB = nullptr;
    A(B *b) {
        pB = b;
    }
    void doSomething() {
        pB->foo = 8;
    }
}
```

B.h:

```c++
#include "A.h"

class B {
    A *a;
    int foo = 3;
    B() {
        a = new A(this);
    }
}
```

I try compiling this, and I get an error inside of `A.h` saying:

```
error: 'B' does not name a type
    B *pB = nullptr
    ^
```

Well I google this and find it's an issue with the circular dependency, so they suggest doing forward declarations and I try implementing it by changing `A.h` to:

```c++
//#include "B.h"
class B;

class A {
    B *pB = nullptr;
    A(B *b) {
        pB = b;
    }
    void doSomething() {
        pB->foo = 8;
    }
}
```

Now I compile and get a different error in `A.h` saying

```
error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class B'
    pB->foo = 8;
      ^~
note: forward declaration of 'class B'
    class B;
          ^
```

Trying to google this tells me I should be including the B class. But that won't work because then I have a circular dependency and it breaks. How am I supposed to fix this properly? I thought forward declarations were supposed to be the proper way of doing it, but that doesn't work either. I tried declaring `foo` inside of the forward declaration and that also didn't work, and I feel would cause more issues in development. I'm using the GCC compiler, VSCode, and running on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: You are accessing into an incomplete type in `doSomething()`. You can circumvent this by declaring `doSomething` and defining it once `B` is fully declared. Note that this is also the way you would write a standard `C++` program. Declare stuff in the header and implement them in the source

Comment: You'll need to provide separate compilation units for the implementation to get this working.